# Error when launching Java FX application on a headless Linux RedHat system

Tags: java, linux, javafx, rhel

Trying to launch a java FX application on a Linux system using X. I get the following stack trace. After a bunch of googling and installing various packages, I am at a loss.  Any thoughts?

```
java -jar tacoma_testing.jar 
Prism-ES2 Error : GL_VERSION (major.minor) = 1.4
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.launchApp(Main.java:698)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:871)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /projects/tacoma/tacoma_regression_testing/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/amd64/libglass.so: libgio-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:281)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:124)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:163)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /projects/tacoma/tacoma_regression_testing/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/amd64/libglass.so: libgio-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1957)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1882)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1843)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1061)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFullPath(NativeLibLoader.java:200)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:88)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:31)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.loadNativeLibrary(Application.java:73)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.loadNativeLibrary(Application.java:80)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory$1.run(GtkPlatformFactory.java:28)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory$1.run(GtkPlatformFactory.java:25)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.<clinit>(GtkPlatformFactory.java:25)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.PlatformFactory.getPlatformFactory(PlatformFactory.java:20)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.Run(Application.java:103)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:271)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: you have a major-minor error i.e. the jar you are using is compiled with a different JRE version that you are currently using !

Answer (score 1):

Redhat is not listed as as [supported configuration](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html) for JavaFX 2.2.
Nor is running JavaFX in a headless mode.

This may change for Java 8, but Java 8 has not been released yet, so the list of supported configurations for JavaFX running on Java 8 has not been published.

Currently the supported configuration set for Linux is only => Ubuntu 10.4+ gtk2 2.18+ with optional additional requirements for av codecs if you also want media playback support.

So try using a supported Ubuntu system instead of Redhat and you may or may not get that working in a headless environment.

> I tested and it works fine with Redhat 6. Redhat 5 seems to be the problem.

Redhat Enterprise Linux 6 support will be added for Java 8 (to be released in the next few weeks).

A RHEL 5.5 support request was closed as won't fix, see [RT-22564 "JavaFX Support for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.5"](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-22564).

If you can find a way to install gtk2 2.18+ on RHEL 5 you may be able to get it to work, though no promises.

Comment: I tested and it works fine with Redhat 6. Redhat 5 seems to be the problem. Unfortunately, my client is a large corporation and change is slow. So I either have to convince them to have a newer box to support this one application, or port the whole thing to AWT.